# Pseudo Class and Css Role how to apply theme

Tags: html, css

I have a div and span tag. Something like:

```
<div>Test <span class="link-action"><a href="url">Link text</a></span></div>
```

At the moment I'm using this code but I'm not able to make the link white

```
a.link-action:link
{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: what about removing the `:link`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `link-action` class is on the `span`, not the `a`:

```
span.link-action a:link
{
    color: #fff;
}
```